# Lambda function not executed in dictionary with "if-else" values

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, lambda

I'm trying to define different lambda functions in a Python dictionary. I know that probably the best thing to do is to have only one lambda function in the "value" part of the dictionary item and manage subcases inside the definded function, but however I don't understand why this code is not working like I want:

```
def a():
    print('a')


def b():
    print('b')


def c():
    print('c')


def d():
    print('d')

condition = True

dict = {
        'foo': lambda: a() if condition else lambda: b(),
        'bar': lambda: c() if condition else lambda: d()
    }.get('foo', lambda: print('not found'))()
```

if we set condition = False, the code will not print b, it will not do anything (it seems)..why?
Instead if we try with a dictionary without lambda function definitions, it seems to work as I expect:

```
dict2 = {
        'foo': 4 if condition else 5,
        'bar': 6 if condition else 7
    }.get('foo', -1)
```

dict2 will be 5.

Someone can explain to me why the definition returned in the first case is not working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use `lambda`. Just use `a() if condition else b()`

Comment: You better read on `lambda functions`. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: @bigbounty I dont't think it will do the same: if I'm not wrong, all lines of the dictionary will be executed.

Comment: @bigbounty I think OP is trying to achieve something like lazy eval. So that won't work

Comment: Lambdas here are unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambdas:

`lambda: a() if condition else lambda: b()`

Are actually:

`(lambda: a() if condition else (lambda: b()))`

So if `condition == False`, you return lambda, if `True` - you use `a()`

Anyway, lambdas here are unnecessary. You can replace it with:

```
dict_ = {
        'foo': a if condition else b,
        'bar': c if condition else d
    }.get('foo', lambda: print('not found'))()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote is equivalent to:

```
def a():
    print('a')


def b():
    print('b')


def c():
    print('c')


def d():
    print('d')

condition = True

dict = {
        'foo': lambda: (a() if condition else lambda: b()),
        'bar': lambda: (c() if condition else lambda: d())
    }.get('foo', lambda: print('not found'))()
```

It means that the code after the first lambda is considered one block of function. What you want is:

```
def a():
    print('a')


def b():
    print('b')


def c():
    print('c')


def d():
    print('d')

condition = True

dict = {
        'foo': (lambda: a()) if condition else (lambda: b()),
        'bar': (lambda: c()) if condition else (lambda: d())
    }.get('foo', lambda: print('not found'))()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem here due to operator precedence. You need to parenthesise the `lambdas`:

```
(lambda: a()) if condition else (lambda: b())
```

What your code does is this:

```
lambda: (a() if condition else lambda: b())
```

Which creates a function that either returns `a()` or returns *another function* that returns `b()`.

By parenthesising each `lambda`, you get proper execution: either a function returning `a()` or one returning `b()`

If `condition` is `False`, your function call actually returns this:

```
<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x...>
```